# MYSQL JSON_SET adds backslash

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, mysql-json

I want to update JSON array in the database

I'v got this array:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 34
    [var1] => val1
    [var2] => val2
    [var3] => val3
)
```

and I need to update json by the id

query sample:

```
JOSN_SET(`json_arr`,'$."34"','{"id":"34","var1":"val1","var2":"val2","var3":"val3"}')
```

expected result :

```
{"34":{"id":"34","var1":"val1","var2":"val2","var3":"val3"}}
```

result :

```
{"34":"{\"id\":\"34\",\"var1\":\"val1\",\"var2\":\"val2\",\"var3\":\"val3\"}"}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you using the ->> operator or json_unquote(json_extract()) to get the result?

Answer (score 7):

you should CAST it into JSON, like:

```
JOSN_SET(`json_arr`,'$."34"',CAST('{"id":"34","var1":"val1","var2":"val2","var3":"val3"}' AS JSON))
```